# How to show right panel RStudio

Tags: rstudio

I just hid the right panel and it is very helpful for packages installing, help and a lot of tools.
I have explored all the options and there's no way to bring it back.

This is my screen
[image: My screen (no right panel)]

And this is my friend's screen

[image: Friend screen (right panel is shown)]

Can you help me to show the right panel like my friend please?

Comment: @DanY I can't belive... it was not working before... Thanks, put the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Click the right edge of the screen and drag it inwards.

Or hit Ctrl+Shift+0 which is the "show all panes" commands. This can also be accessed under the menu View > Panes > Show All Panes.